# Apache Spark Databricks ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'

Tags: azure-databricks

I am trying to install the following library on Databricks:

```
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeFileClient
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'
```

Can someone let me know the actual module to install?

Answer (score 0):

This should be `azure-storage-file-datalake` and `pip` based installation.
[image]

[image]

Comment: adding the module fixed the error message. I am now trying to send an html file to my ADLS using the following 
```with open('/pitstops_suite.html', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
file = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=adlspiukadlsdev;AccountKey=X50Mjjqa7GfxW==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net", file_system_name="polybase", file_path="pitstops_suite.html")
file.create_file()
file.append_data(html, offset=0, length=len(html))
file.flush_data(len(html))```

But I'm getting error:  
```ResourceNotFoundError: The specified filesystem does not exist
file.create_file()```